# Iterate over excel-sheets name starts from "Line"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

`xls = pd.ExcelFile('xyz.xlsx')`

I have excel file, and lots of sheets(or tabs) are there for example:- Line 7, Line 9, Introduction, Data, Pack, Outsource, Line 11 and etc.

So my problem is i only want to iterate through those sheets - name starts from "Line". and perform

```
df2 = df1['Unnamed: 1']
df3 = df2[51:59] #72:
df3 = df3.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any') 
df4 = df2[72:] #72:
df4 = df4.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any')
df5 = df4.drop(83)
df6 = pd.concat([df3,df5])
```

this above task for each sheet and store it in a dataframe until all the sheets get appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter sheet names like below

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('xyz.xlsx')
buf = []  # buffer to store results in each loop iteration
#xls.sheet_names
#['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
sheets_needed = [i for i in xls.sheet_names if i.startswith("Line")]
for sheet in sheets_needed:
    df1 = xls.parse(sheet_name=sheet)
    # your operations here
    buf.append(df6)
df = pd.concat(buf)  # your desired output
```

Comment: Thank You so much @crayxt for responding to my question It's working. But one issue is there, After i used your logic i am getting ['Line 7',
 'Line 8',
 'Line 9',
 'Line 11',
 'Line 12',
 'Line 1 YTD',
 'Line 2 YTD',
 'Line 3 YTD',
 'Line 4 YTD',
 'Line 5 YTD'] but i dont want to include those Line which is ending with YTD, i have tried using endswith but not got the right answer, please help

Comment: I found :)   sheets_needed = [i for i in xls.sheet_names if i.startswith("Line") and not i.endswith("YTD")]

Comment: @Ram Good to know. Learning by trial and error is the best method ;)